# Shell script to connect to MySQL server

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I have about 20 different MySQL instances that I'd like to easily connect to without having to input the whole address, username, and crazy long password each time. What can I do to script this process, so all I have to do is run one .sh script for each instance?

What I have so far, saved as "instance1.sh"

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -h instance1-address.com -u username -p password -e "show databases"
```

After making this file executable, it still asks for my password, even though it is in the script itself. What can I do?

Comment: You can put default options in your `.my.cnf` file.

Comment: Our preferred method is to put the options into a file and reference the file with `defaults-extra-file`  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html. (The prompt for a password is happening because mysql isn't seeing "password" as the supplied password, and that's because of the space that follows `-p`. Remove the space e.g. `-pmysecret` and MySQL will take "mysecret" to be the password. Avoid the warning by using an options file instead of supplying the password on the command line. )

Comment: putting the username and pwd in a config file, then referring to that in the .sh still forces me to enter the password:
my.cnf:
`[client] username="usr"
password="mysecret"`
.sh:
`#!/bin/bash mysql -h instancehere.com -u$USERNAME -p$PASSWORD`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

remove the space after `-p` so like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -h instance1-address.com -u username -ppassword -e "show databases"
```

it will still show a warning about it being insecure

Comment: Do you need to 'disconnect' from mysql server inside such script?