# connect to mysql db and execute query and export result to variable - bash script

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I want to connect to mysql databse and execute some queries and export its result to a varibale, and do all of these need to be done entirely by bash script

I have a snippet code but does not work.

```
#!/bin/bash

BASEDIR=$(dirname $0)
cd $BASEDIR

mysqlUser=n_userdb
mysqlPass=d2FVR0NA3
mysqlDb=n_datadb

result=$(mysql -u $mysqlUser -p$mysqlPass -D $mysqlDb -e "select * from confs limit 1")

echo "${result}" >> a.txt
```

whats the problem ?

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't just redirect the output of `mysql` into a file directly?  Also, what does not work and in what way (error messages?). You also need to double quote _all_ variable expansions.

Comment: check this previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42865795/shell-script-to-connect-to-mysql-server

Comment: @Corrupted_S.K Unrelated. There is no issue with the `-p` option in the given code (except they should be using a `my.cnf` file instead).

Comment: @Kusalananda even after I redirect output into a file directly, didnt save anything into the file and file content is empty yet

Comment: Are you getting error messages or warnings?

Comment: @Kusalananda I haven't any direct access to shell and only can write my codes in the .sh files and execute them by cronjob and direct output to a file and check results in that file. my snippet don't write any result in 'a.txt' file and this means it doesn't make any error

Comment: No, it means that the errors are not saved to the output file since you are only redirecting standard output, not standard error.  Redirect the error stream with `mysql ... 2>a-err.txt`. The errors would then be available in `a-err.txt`.

Comment: @Kusalananda I used your guide and got this message: `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'allcoin_userdb'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` but I connect to mysql via this config by php. why I can't connect from shell. now what I must do ?

Comment: Try using `-h 127.0.0.1` with `mysql`. MySQL treats `localhost` as distinct from `127.0.0.1` (the IP address of `localhost`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174084/discussion-between-saeid-and-kusalananda).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved [in the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174084/discussion-between-saeid-and-kusalananda) by using the correct password.

If you further want to get *only the data*, use `mysql` with `-NB` (or `--skip-column-names` and `--batch`).

Also, the script needs to quote the variable expansions, or there will be issues with usernames/passwords containing characters that are special to the shell. Additionally, uppercase variable names are usually reserved for system variables.

```
#!/bin/sh

basedir=$(dirname "$0")

mysqlUser='n_userdb'
mysqlPass='d2FVR0NA3'
mysqlDb='n_datadb'

cd "$basedir" &&
mysql -NB -u "$mysqlUser" -p"$mysqlPass" -D "$mysqlDb" \
      -e 'select * from confs limit 1' >a.txt 2>a-err.txt
```

Ideally though, you'd use a `my.cnf` file to configure the username and password.

See e.g.

- [MySQL Utilities - ~/.my.cnf option file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16299603/mysql-utilities-my-cnf-option-file)
- [mysql .my.cnf not reading credentials properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300501/mysql-my-cnf-not-reading-credentials-properly)

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
result=$(mysql -u $mysqlUser -p$mysqlPass -D $mysqlDb -e "select * from confs limit 1" | grep '^\|' | tail -1)
```

The $() statement of Bash has trouble handling variables which contain multiple lines so the above hack greps only the interesting part: the data

Comment: Bash has _no_ issue with variable containing multiple lines.

Comment: OK sorry i misspoke. Bash has no trouble doing that but the command $() does. @saeid What's the content of a.txt, what exactly did you type and do you get any error message? It works fine for me.

Comment: @Kusalananda Do we agree on my way of expressing it now since I edited?

Comment: No sorry, you still claim that `bash` has some sort of issue with multi-line strings in variables. I'm not sure from where you get this.

Comment: @Kusalananda No I simply mean that putting all lines into one when using multiline $( ) in Bash is a poor way of handling it.